# From a deck of $52$ cards, a $5$-card hand is dealt. Find the number of hands containing exactly one pair

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From a deck of $52$ cards, a $5$-card hand is dealt. Find the number of hands containing exactly one pair without  considering the variation of the suits?

my attempt to solve it :
split the $52$ into $13$ subset of $4$ identical items now I will choose one pair
then I will choose one from each subset and then removing duplicates?
$$  ^{13}C_1 \times (\frac{^{12}C_1 \times ^{11}C_1 \times ^{11}C_1}{3!})$$

Comment: yes! I mean the number of hands with one pair regardless what suite is

Comment: I am asking about the number of hands!

Comment: there's no $\times ^{13}$.  ?

Comment: Yes, I understand the notation now.  Everything is right except the $.5$.

Comment: I am removing the variation that the pair is before the other 3 or after it?

Comment: We're talking about a combination of $5$ cards.  Order doesn't come into it.  There are $13$ ways to choose the rank with the pair, and $\binom{12}3$ ways to choose the other $3$ ranks.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: got it. Thank you!

Comment: "without considering the variation of the suits" does that mean that a pair of Jacks with a 10, 4, and a Queen should count as one hand (instead of $\binom 42 4^3$ hands) ?

Comment: @WW1 That's how I interpret it.  Just the hand patterns, not the actual hands.

Comment: @saulspatz I would say that a hand with e.g. `2 2 3 3 3` also contains exactly one pair. So there is a little more combination than $$13 \cdot \binom{12}{3}$$ We also need to count hands contain one pair and a tripple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without considering the suits**, my approach would be:

The pair can be one of 13 numbers, i.e. we need to pick 1 out of 13 candidates.

For the remaining 3 cards there are two possibilities.

1. They can be 3 cards with identical number. In this case we need to pick 1 out of 12 candidates.

or

2. They can be 3 cards with different numbers. In this case we need to pick 3 out of 12 candidates.

Which gives us:

$$\binom{13}{1} \cdot (\binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{3}) = 13 \cdot (12 + 220) = 3016$$

**EDIT**

In comments it's discussed whether or not 3 cards with identical numbers represent a pair or even 3 pairs.

To me a hand like `2 2 3 3 3` contains exactly **one pair** and **one triple**. To me it's  **not** a hand with 2 pairs nor is it a hand with 4 pairs (which has been suggested in comments).

Anyway - **if a triple counts as 3 pairs** the answer to the question is even simpler. Just remove the hands containing a triple.

$$\binom{13}{1} \cdot \binom{12}{3} = 13 \cdot 220 = 2860$$

However, I disagree with considering "3 of a kind as 3 pairs". Consider this example. The hand is `3 3 3 4 5`. Now put your first pair on the table. So `3 3` goes to the table and the remaining hand is `3 4 5`. Now put your second pair on the table. You can't ... there is no pair in `3 4 5`.

So if a triple is to be considered also as pair, it must (IMO) be as exactly one pair. In that case the calculation changes to include hands like `2 2 2 3 4`. So **if a triple counts as 1 pair** the calculation is:

$$\binom{13}{1} \cdot (\binom{12}{2} + \binom{12}{3}) = 13 \cdot (66 + 220) = 3718$$

Comment: In the question it's just one pair!

Comment: @IbrahimAbouElenein If you have 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 then you have **exactly** one pair.

Comment: the 3 and 3 are making a pair!

Comment: @IbrahimAbouElenein Well, `3 3 3` would never be called a pair.  To be a pair there must be exactly two of the same number. If there is 3 of the same number it's no longer a pair. So `2 2 3 3 3` has exactly 1 pair while `2 2 3 3 4` has two pairs.

Comment: If you have three cards of the same rank, then there are three pairs of that rank (depending on which of the three cards you exclude).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig well, I disagree. To me 3 cards with identical values doesn't count as 3 pairs. We need a 5 card hand so we can't just exclude a card. Further the task says: " without considering the variation of the suits" so the pairs wouldn't differ. Anyway - I changed the answer to include the "3 of a kind is also 3 pairs" view point.

Comment: In [poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands), a pair consists of two cards of one rank and one card each from three other ranks.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig True but a) poker isn't mentioned in the Q and b) in poker a "full house" is defined as "Combination of three of a kind and a pair", i.e. exactly one pair. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em So to me a "full house is a hand with exactly one pair" Anyway - the answer has been updated to cover other interpretations than mine.